# Filter queryset with one of two criteria that match with the user. Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

and of course, it returns every message.

A Message is so in the model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    type = models.CharField(_('type'), choices=MESSAGE_TYPE, default='Invitation', max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'), blank=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender_message', verbose_name=_("Sender"), )
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver_message', null=True, blank=True,
                                  verbose_name=_("Recipient"))
    url_profile_image = models.URLField(_('url_profile_image'), max_length=500, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

and the serializer is so:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sender.uuid')
    recipient = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='recipient.uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'type', 'content', 'sender', 'recipient', 'url_profile_image')
```

I just want that the queryset returns a message if the user is the sender or the recipient.

I was trying with this:

```
filter_backends = filters.DjangoFilterBackend
filter_fields = ('recipient', 'sender')
```

But it doesn't work, perhaps, because I don't know where to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `get_queryset` method on the viewset rather than the `queryset` field.

You can then access the request object to access the current user.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Message.objects.filter(Q(recipient=self.request.user) | Q(sender=self.request.user))
```

You can find another [example in the docs for `ModelViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example_1)

Comment: nice. but I have to let this ```queryset = Message.objects.all()```  though. Isn't it? 
I mean, I let it and it works. And when I take it away I get an error. 
(Do you know why it happens?)
Thanks!!

Comment: @ChuckAguilar - I can't remember at the minute, I don't have any source in front of me so can't remember what error you receive

Comment: ```assert queryset is not None, '`base_name` argument not specified, and could ' \ AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
```
But it's ok, I mean, when I let the queryset so, as I had it, with the get_query function, it works nicely.

Comment: @ChuckAguilar - Ah I see, if you go to the example I link to under my question there is a paragraph about it - "Note however that upon removal of the queryset property from your ViewSet...."